# Error building wxWidgets DLLs with GCC's Link Time Optimization on Windows

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, wxwidgets, mingw-w64

**When attempting to build the wxWidgets 3.1.0 library with the following command line:**

> mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=1 CFLAGS="-O2 -flto"
>   CXXFLAGS="-O2 -flto" LDFLAGS="-O2 -flto"

I'm getting  this warning (31 occurrences)

```
lto1.exe: warning: -fPIC ignored for target (all code is position independent)
```

Followed by:

```
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans6.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x13c4): undefined reference to `wx_regfree'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans6.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x1418): undefined reference to `wx_regfree'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans6.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x3792): undefined reference to `wx_regerror'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans6.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x37c1): undefined reference to `wx_regerror'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans6.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x3a7d): undefined reference to `wx_re_exec'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans6.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x47de): undefined reference to `wx_re_comp'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans6.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x4cf4): undefined reference to `wx_regfree'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans6.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x4f94): undefined reference to `wx_regfree'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans12.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x57c): undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans12.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x88d): undefined reference to `deflateSetDictionary'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans12.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x8ba): undefined reference to `deflateSetDictionary'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans12.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x947): undefined reference to `deflate'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans12.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x4830): undefined reference to `deflate'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans12.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x59f4): undefined reference to `deflateInit2_'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans14.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x3354): undefined reference to `deflateReset'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans14.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x38db): undefined reference to `inflateReset'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans16.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x21d): undefined reference to `inflateSetDictionary'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans16.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x24a): undefined reference to `inflateSetDictionary'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans16.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x266): undefined reference to `zlibVersion'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans16.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x27d): undefined reference to `zlibVersion'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans16.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x2d0): undefined reference to `zlibVersion'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans16.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x121c): undefined reference to `inflate'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans16.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x1924): undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans16.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x20b7): undefined reference to `inflateInit2_'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans16.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x3694): undefined reference to `crc32'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans16.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x5534): undefined reference to `crc32'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans16.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x5813): undefined reference to `crc32'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans16.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x773e): undefined reference to `crc32'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccEDEhIg.ltrans16.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x7c5b): undefined reference to `crc32'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile.gcc:5299: recipe for target '..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxbase310u_gcc_custom.dll' failed
mingw32-make: *** [..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxbase310u_gcc_custom.dll] Error 1
```

Last lines emmited by the compiler and linker, which results in all these errors, are as follows:

```
g++ -c -o gcc_mswudll\basedll_main.o  -O2 -mthreads  -DHAVE_W32API_H -D__WXMSW__   -DNDEBUG    -D_UNICODE -I..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu -I..\..\include  -W -Wall -DWXBUILDING -I..\..\src\tiff\libtiff -I..\..\src\jpeg -I..\..\src\png -I..\..\src\zlib -I..\..\src\regex -I..\..\src\expat\lib -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -DWXMAKINGDLL_BASE -DwxUSE_BASE=1   -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy  -O2 -flto -MTgcc_mswudll\basedll_main.o -MFgcc_mswudll\basedll_main.o.d -MD -MP ../../src/msw/main.cpp
g++ -c -o gcc_mswudll\basedll_volume.o  -O2 -mthreads  -DHAVE_W32API_H -D__WXMSW__   -DNDEBUG    -D_UNICODE -I..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswu -I..\..\include  -W -Wall -DWXBUILDING -I..\..\src\tiff\libtiff -I..\..\src\jpeg -I..\..\src\png -I..\..\src\zlib -I..\..\src\regex -I..\..\src\expat\lib -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -DWXMAKINGDLL_BASE -DwxUSE_BASE=1   -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy  -O2 -flto -MTgcc_mswudll\basedll_volume.o -MFgcc_mswudll\basedll_volume.o.d -MD -MP ../../src/msw/volume.cpp
g++ -shared -fPIC -o ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\wxbase310u_gcc_custom.dll gcc_mswudll\basedll_dummy.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_version_rc.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_any.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_appbase.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_arcall.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_arcfind.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_archive.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_arrstr.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_base64.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_clntdata.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_cmdline.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_config.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_convauto.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_datetime.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_datetimefmt.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_datstrm.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_dircmn.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_dynarray.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_dynlib.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_dynload.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_encconv.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_evtloopcmn.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_extended.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_ffile.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_file.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_fileback.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_fileconf.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_filefn.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_filename.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_filesys.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_filtall.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_filtfind.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_fmapbase.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_fs_arc.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_fs_filter.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_hash.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_hashmap.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_init.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_intl.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_ipcbase.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_languageinfo.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_list.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_log.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_longlong.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_memory.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_mimecmn.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_module.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_mstream.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_numformatter.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_object.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_platinfo.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_powercmn.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_process.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_regex.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_stdpbase.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_sstream.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_stdstream.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_stopwatch.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_strconv.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_stream.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_string.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_stringimpl.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_stringops.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_strvararg.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_sysopt.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_tarstrm.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_textbuf.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_textfile.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_threadinfo.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_time.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_timercmn.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_timerimpl.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_tokenzr.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_translation.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_txtstrm.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_unichar.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_uri.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_ustring.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_variant.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_wfstream.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_wxcrt.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_wxprintf.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_xlocale.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_xti.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_xtistrm.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_zipstrm.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_zstream.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_fswatchercmn.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_fswatcherg.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_basemsw.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_crashrpt.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_debughlp.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_dde.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_dir.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_dlmsw.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_evtloopconsole.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_mimetype.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_power.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_regconf.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_registry.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_snglinst.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_stackwalk.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_stdpaths.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_thread.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_timer.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_utils.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_utilsexc.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_fswatcher.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_event.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_fs_mem.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_msgout.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_utilscmn.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_main.o gcc_mswudll\basedll_volume.o   -mthreads -L..\..\lib\gcc_dll -Wl,--out-implib=..\..\lib\gcc_dll\libwxbase31u.a  -O2 -flto  -lwxzlib -lwxregexu -lwxexpat   -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lshlwapi -lcomctl32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lrpcrt4 -ladvapi32 -lversion -lwsock32 -lwininet
```

**What I've tried so far:**

- Added `-fPIC` to CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS, to no avail.
- Use `-fwhopr` instead of `-flto`, as suggested by the [MinGW-w64 Wiki](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/LTO%20and%20GCC/) but it's not recognized by either *gcc.exe* and *g++.exe*. After reading this article: [Linktime optimization in GCC, part 1 - brief history](http://hubicka.blogspot.com.br/2014/04/linktime-optimization-in-gcc-1-brief.html), I'm assuming the `-fwhopr` option doesn't exist anymore and is now the default mode for the `-flto` switch.
- Build the static configuration (`SHARED=0`). It builds successfully, but is unusable. See *Reference #1*.
- Omit `-flto` from LDFLAGS - i.e. use `-flto` in CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS only. Also no avail.

**How to get past these errors, and build wxWidgets with GCC's Link Time Optimization?**
I'm building with MinGW-w64; threading model *Win32*; exception handling *DWARF*; GCC version 5.3.0.

---

**Reference #1:** Result from the "Minimal Sample" build command line

```
H:\temp\wxwidgets-3.1.0\samples\minimal>mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=0 CFLAGS="-O2 -flto" CXXFLAGS="-O2 -flto" LDFLAGS="-O2 -flto"
windres --use-temp-file -i../../samples/sample.rc -ogcc_mswu\minimal_sample_rc.o    --define __WXMSW__   --define NDEBUG    --define _UNICODE --include-dir .\..\..\lib\gcc_lib\mswu --include-dir ./../../include  --include-dir .  --include-dir ./../../samples --define NOPCH
g++ -c -o gcc_mswu\minimal_minimal.o  -O2 -mthreads  -DHAVE_W32API_H -D__WXMSW__   -DNDEBUG    -D_UNICODE -I.\..\..\lib\gcc_lib\mswu -I.\..\..\include  -W -Wall -I.  -I.\..\..\samples -DNOPCH   -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy  -O2 -flto -MTgcc_mswu\minimal_minimal.o -MFgcc_mswu\minimal_minimal.o.d -MD -MP minimal.cpp
g++ -o gcc_mswu\minimal.exe gcc_mswu\minimal_sample_rc.o gcc_mswu\minimal_minimal.o   -mthreads -L.\..\..\lib\gcc_lib -Wl,--subsystem,windows -mwindows  -O2 -flto  -lwxmsw31u_core  -lwxbase31u    -lwxtiff -lwxjpeg -lwxpng   -lwxzlib -lwxregexu -lwxexpat   -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lshlwapi -lcomctl32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lrpcrt4 -ladvapi32 -lversion -lwsock32 -lwininet
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccY1ZbWs.ltrans0.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x191): undefined reference to `wxDefaultPosition'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccY1ZbWs.ltrans0.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x197): undefined reference to `wxDefaultPosition'
C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Temp\ccY1ZbWs.ltrans0.ltrans.o:<artificial>:(.text+0x1a8): undefined reference to `wxDefaultSize'

(Many, many other "undefined reference" errors - probably one for every function the code ever depends on) and then...

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile.gcc:221: recipe for target 'gcc_mswu\minimal.exe' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswu\minimal.exe] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried using LTO with DLLs before, but there are apparently bugs with doing it, see e.g. [this one](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/486/). Not sure if using the workaround proposed there can help in your case.

What I think should *definitely* work would be compiling your application sources and wxWidgets together at once, this would be similar to building a static library but shouldn't optimize away things unused in the library -- but used in the application code.

Finally, I'm really not sure if you're going to achieve much with LTO in wxWidgets case. There is not that much "slow" code to optimize in the library...

Comment: Thank you for your input on this one, VZ. My goal is actually to benchmark it with some automated tests. I'll keep trying.